# How to do server-side backpressure in gRPC?

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, grpc, backpressure, grpc-c++

I just find that in C++, when using AsyncService, even if I don't request a new request, gRPC will still read data from the network. This caused a huge memory usage in my system.

Detailed Scenario:

I have a client that will send a lot of requests to the server.

On the server-side, I didn't request any requests. The server blocked in `cq_->Next(&tag, &ok)` but was kept consuming memory. Caused an OOM in my system.

So my question is how to prevent the server from reading data from the network when I don't request a new request? i.e. how to do server-side backpressure so I can save the memory??

Could anyone help me? thanks!

#### EDIT: Reproduce

I made a simple example for you to reproduce this problem, the code is based on the `v1.46.3` tag of the official gRPC code base. I just modified the example to make the server don't request any requests and make the client send more requests. Check [this commit](https://github.com/lixin-wei/grpc/commit/8021abbdb6e867fe9be81c49c01fd033b3380135) for what I modified.

1. `git clone -b v1.46.3_reproduce_oom --depth 1 https://github.com/lixin-wei/grpc.git && cd grpc`
2. `git submodule update --init`
3. `bazel build //examples/cpp/helloworld:all`
4. in one session, start server: `./bazel-bin/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server`
5. in aonther session, start client: `./bazel-bin/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2`
6. keep running `ps -aux | grep greeter_async_server`, you'll notice an increasing memory usage in the server.

The server code is `examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc`, the client code is `examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc`.

Comment: "gRPC will still read data from the network" What data would gRPC read then? Can't read data if there is none.

Comment: @MarcusMüller According to the stack in the memory dump, it's in `init_header_frame_parser`, so I believe it's reading header data.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 'Can't read data if there is none.' There is data in the network, the client sent it. I just don't request any requests in the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't request any requests"? It is the client that "requests". Are you saying that the server tells the client when to request, but in your case it does that even though it was told not to do that? That sounds (a) like a weird and complicated design and (b) as a bug on the client side.

Comment: @freakish No, by saying request a request in the server, I mean 'Adding handler to handle new request'. The API in gRPC server is called `AsyncService::RequestXXX`.

Comment: Some funny bones love the non-blocking communication and poll their hearts out any chance they get, wasting CPU cycles and resources in a hysterical "must...not...block" frenzy. I bet 1 reputation, that this is the root cause here, also :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `ResourceQuota` to restrict buffer memory usage across the server. The size you specify is not an absolute system memory limit, since not all memory in gRPC core/C++ is tracked, but it will result in a cap on the total memory usage.

In the server, you can add:

```
    // Set a maximum memory cap
    grpc::ResourceQuota quota("greeter_callback_server");
    quota.Resize(30*1024*1024); // 30MB
    builder.SetResourceQuota(quota);
```

And after a memory cap is reached, adding the error code to the client output, the clients will see something like

```
RPC failed with: Received RST_STREAM with error code 11
```

On my system, this happens when the server processes reach ~140MB RES memory.

---

**Edit**: another option is to set the maximum number of concurrent streams that the server is willing to accept using the `GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` channel argument. Each unary call is a separate RPC, and handled as a separate stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added ResourceQuota in my example but it didn't work. The server's memory still reaches 8GB+. Would you please try my example in the problem description?

Comment: I think ResourceQuota can't solve this, see https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/9GpwvQiB9uk?pli=1

Comment: I did try your example myself, and verified that the fix works. If you set the ResourceQuota to something like 100MB (100*1024*1024), you should see memory stop growing at some small multiple of that number (I'd guess under 1GB).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But wired it really doesn't work in my machine. Would you please take a look at what I wrote? Did I write it correctly? https://github.com/lixin-wei/grpc/commit/af179984b0d938a9106a7f4055d0d7133a31e991

Comment: Try something extreme like `quota.Resize(5);`. Do your clients not receive RST then? Are you sure they're communicating with that specific server process, and not some other process still running previously?

Comment: I just tried your example again, and the memory is growing without bound in both the async and callback server (though it's harder to tell in the callback server case). Please file a bug against gRPC to investigate it.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort! I believe gRPC doesn't made this according to the google group link I sent in me second comment.